# Approximations of Euler's constant using $\pi$

Tags: logarithms, recreational-mathematics, approximation, pi, euler-mascheroni-constant

Disclaimer: This is for recreational purposes.

Hello MSE! So while my research paper about Euler's constant $\gamma$, I created this amazing approximation for it: $$\frac{\pi^2}{12000}-\ln((10^{-3})!)*1000$$Which is correct to almost six digits (where $!$ is extended to the real numbers). However, I don't like the look of the logarithm of a factorial. So out of curiosity, are there any other interesting approximations of $\gamma$ using $\pi$? I'm fine with logarithms but factorials are just too ugly.

Edit: I only asked for an approximation of $\gamma$ using $\pi$'s. There is no other question here.

Comment: What does $(10^{-3})!$ mean?  Usually the factorial is applied to natural numbers.  Are you shortenting this for a $\Gamma$-function?

Comment: @Randall I edited the OP. Thanks for pointing this out :)

Comment: Are finite-$n$ truncations of [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_constant#Asymptotic_expansions) of interest? Some of them include $\pi$.

Comment: @J.G. They're fine. But if they contained no logarithms then that would be great.

Comment: 6 digits from such a complex expression does not seem very exciting.  There are more than 6 digits in the expression.  How about $0\pi + 0.577215$?

Comment: @badjohn it was exciting since the pi has an exponent. Also, I think you know what I mean about having a pi in the estimate.

Comment: Yes, I knew what you meant but with so many more elements, you could get almost anything to 6 digits e.g. the speed of light.

Comment: @badjohn so you were joking? That was a great example then 

Comment: @KamalSaleh Half joke, half serious.  It would be impressive if there were fewer than 6 digits in the expression.  Achieving 6 digits by using more than 6 digits in your expression is the unimpressive aspect.  I was trying to show in a humorous fashion that it is easy,

Comment: Here's another $\sqrt \pi - 1.195238$.

Comment: who ever keeps downvoting my questions, please stop. I am fed up with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you think about this one $\gamma\approx\dfrac{\pi}{2e}\times\dfrac{8907511}{8917511}$ with $10$ correct decimals.

I proceeded from the rough $\frac{\pi}{2e}$ approximation, then searched the decimals in the [Plouffe inverter](http://wayback.cecm.sfu.ca/cgi-bin/isc/lookup?number=0.00112264796908888860907230104&lookup_type=simple) and choose something simple which was close.

I guess you can derive many fancy approximations using this method, provided you get something nice around the desired decimals in the inverter. If not try another starting approximation.

Comment: The fact that the numerator has seven digits and the denominator around eight but the approximation gives ten digits makes your approximation great. It is also great that there is an Euler’s number mixed in to make some confusion ;)

Comment: How about this one, to 11 digits? $$\gamma \approx \frac{\pi}{2e} - \frac{521}{804 +2 \times 10^{-5}}$$

Comment: @EricSnyder how about you make this an answer? I will upvote it :)

Answer (score 5):

How about
$$ \gamma \approx 
\frac{7 \pi^{14}-24 \pi^{13}-13 \pi^{12}-18 \pi^{11}-4 \pi^{10}+3 \pi^{9}+20 \pi^{8}-10 \pi^{7}+11 \pi^{6}-4 \pi^{5}-12 \pi^{4}+37 \pi^{3}+9 \pi^{2}-4}{-3 \pi^{14}-2 \pi^{13}-8 \pi^{12}+\pi^{11}-5 \pi^{10}+13 \pi^{9}+6 \pi^{8}}$$
with error about $2.76 \times 10^{-27}$
or
$$ \gamma \approx 
\frac{15 \pi^{9}-47 \pi^{8}+31 \pi^{7}-39 \pi^{6}+56 \pi^{5}-21 \pi^{4}+13 \pi^{3}-12 \pi^{2}-12 \pi -44}{3 \pi^{9}+5 \pi^{8}-3 \pi^{7}+2 \pi^{6}-4 \pi^{5}-37 \pi^{4}+32 \pi^{3}-11 \pi^{2}-4 \pi +10}$$
with error about $1.87 \times 10^{-24}$.

Comment: How did you make that ?

Comment: Using Maple's IntegerRelations package.  I think I used the LLL command.

Answer (score 2):

A very simple one
$$\gamma \sim\frac{26685+102790 \pi }{20080+186403 \pi }$$ the obsolute error is $3.65\times 10^{-21}$

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Wolfram Alpha, for an absolute error of $1.27\times 10^{-101}$

$$\gamma =-\frac{141670595684161}{89719457709126} \binom{\pi }{\pi
   !}+\frac{6168819408880 }{44859728854563}\binom{\pi !}{\pi
   }-$$ $$\frac{115396055527429 }{89719457709126}\binom{\pi !}{\log
   (\pi )}+\frac{144642478651913 }{89719457709126}\binom{\log
   (\pi )}{\pi !}+$$ $$\frac{57273545495261
 }{29906485903042}  \binom{\pi }{\log (\pi )}-\frac{2493037306729
   }{44859728854563}\binom{\log (\pi )}{\pi }$$